# how to manipulate numpy arrays for use with ESRI's arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable

Tags: python, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

ESRI gives access to moving data from tables to arrays and back. I have a script that takes census data from an api call and converts it into arrays, does some simple math, and then, ideally, puts it out into a table. To do the math, the array cannot be a rec array. No combination of vstack, hstack, or concatenate seemed to give a good result. I resorted to creating individual 1-d arrays as recarrays, and then using the merge function in np.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays. surely there is a better way.

ESRI's return from TableToNumPyArray:

```
>>> testArray
array([ (41039000100.0, 2628.0, 100.0, 2339.0, 135.0, 18.0, 22.0, 16.0, 25.0, 0.0, 92.0, 0.0, 92.0, 0.0, 92.0, 0.0, 92.0, 6.0, 9.0, 249.0, 90.0, 0.0, 92.0, 1, u'41039000100'),
...
dtype=[('Geo_id', '<f8'), ('TotalUnits', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total', '<f8'), >('Total_1_detached', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_1_detached', '<f8'), ('Total_1_attached', >'<f8'), ('MOE_Total_1_attached', '<f8'), ('Total_2', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_2', '<f8'), >('Total_3_or_4', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_3_or_4', '<f8'), ('Total_5_to_9', '<f8'), >('MOE_Total_5_to_9', '<f8'), ('Total_10_to_19', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_10_to_19', '<f8'), >('Total_20_to_49', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_20_to_49', '<f8'), ('Total_50_or_more', '<f8'), >('MOE_Total_50_or_more', '<f8'), ('Total_Mobile_home', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_Mobile_home', '<f8'), ('Total_Boat_RV_van_etc', '<f8'), ('MOE_Total_Boat_RV_van_etc', '<f8'), >('ObjectID', '<i4'), ('geo_id_t', '<U50')])
```

My snippet of code looks like

```
try:

    # Assign Geo_id array
    Geo_id_array = B25008_001E_array[...,0]
    Tpop_array = B25008_001E_array[...,1]
    Tunits_array = B25024_001E_array[...,1]
    # divide by sero is possible for real rowns and definite for the end-of-file
    # tract, so convert nan's in the HHsize_array to zero's with nan_to_num
    # HHsize_array = Tpop_array.view(np.float32)/Tunits_array.view(np.float32)
    HHsize_array = Tpop_array/Tunits_array
    HHsize_array = nan_to_num(HHsize_array)
    # Table_array = array(vstack((Geo_id_array, Tpop_array, Tunits_array, HHsize_array)), dtype = ([('Geo_id', '|S13'), ('Tpop', np.int32), ('Tunits_array', np.int32), ('HHsize', np.float32)]))
    # Table_array = np.hstack((Geo_id_array, Tpop_array, Tunits_array, HHsize_array))
    Geo_id_recarray = np.array(Geo_id_array, dtype = ([('Geo_id', '|S13')]))
    Tpop_recarray = np.array(Tpop_array, dtype = ([('Tpop', np.int32)]))
    Tunits_recarray = np.array(Tunits_array, dtype = ([('Tunits_array', np.int32)]))
    HHsize_recarray = np.array(HHsize_array, dtype = ([('HHsize', np.float32)]))
    arrays = [Geo_id_recarray, Tpop_recarray, Tunits_recarray, HHsize_recarray]
    MergedArray = np.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays(arrays, usemask=False)
    print
    print



except Exception as e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "An error occured on line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print str(e)
```

I'd prefer to merge/join/stack the arrays before structuring them, I think. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like all the information you have is in your `testArray`.  Why don't you just use the fields from `testArray` that you need instead of creating several more one-field arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the structured arrays (technically you're not using [recarrays](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray)) to do the "simple math."  I'm not sure if you're showing the math you'd like to do, but for example if you want to do:

```
HHsize_array = Tpop_array/Tunits_array
```

But don't want to have all those separate arrays, you could simply do the math on [views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of the main (merged array), let's call it `data`:

```
data['HHsize'] = data['Tpop']/data['Tunits']
```

where `HHsize`, `Tpop`, and `Tunits` are all field names in one structured array called `data`, such that you'd have

```
>>> data.dtype
dtype([('Geo_id', '|S13'), ('Tpop', np.int32), ('Tunits_array', np.int32), ('HHsize', np.float32)])
```